# Get highlighted text in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

There are plenty of answers on stackoverflow.
I used this code:

```
function getSelectedText() {
    var text = "";
    var activeEl = document.activeElement;
    var activeElTagName = activeEl ? activeEl.tagName.toLowerCase() : null;
    if (
      (activeElTagName == "textarea" || activeElTagName == "input") &&
      /^(?:text|search|password|tel|url)$/i.test(activeEl.type) &&
      (typeof activeEl.selectionStart == "number")
    ) {
        text = activeEl.value.slice(activeEl.selectionStart, activeEl.selectionEnd);
    }else if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    }else if (document.selection) {
        return document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return text;
}
```

It works good on many sites, but on many sites, where code is generated on the fly (using react), like udacity, above function gives empty text.

It occurs when I select text inside code window in on of the udacity courses.

Why above function returns empty text and what is a workaround?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could be due to the use of iframes. If the code window runs in an iframe, document.activeElement won't refer to the active element inside the iframe. THen you have to select the iframe eocument and get the activeElement there.

Comment: How can I select active iframe document?

Comment: Also, it appears, that there is no iframe.